# PyQGIS Processing - wrong number of parameters

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-processing, voronoi-thiessen

I'm facing a very strange issue from the module Processing using it as a standalone (not in the Qgis python console). I'm trying to create voronoi polygons from a points csv file. I can load my file without issue but the Processing.runAlgorithm always fail with " wrong number of arguments ". There are only 3 arguments described in the help.

```
#create uri
uri = "file://{}?delimiter={}&xField={}&yField={}".format(os.path.abspath(fichier.name),",","x","y")
#open file
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "tmp", "delimitedtext")

# check
if not layer.isValid():
    print "Layer didn't load properly."
    print "Check your filename and the file integrity."

# UTF-8
layer.setProviderEncoding('UTF-8')

#feedback
print("File successfully loaded as " + layer.name() + " layer.")


Processing.runAlgorithm("qgis:voronoipolygons",layer,0.0, "test2.shp")
```

Traceback :

```
File successfully loaded as tmp layer.
Error: Wrong number of parameters
ALGORITHM: Voronoi polygons
    INPUT <ParameterVector>
    BUFFER <ParameterNumber>
    OUTPUT <OutputVector>
```

but it works from the Qgis python console :

```
mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()
layers = mapcanvas.layers()
processing.runalg("qgis:voronoipolygons",layers[0],0.0,"test.shp")
```

Output :

```
{'OUTPUT': 'test.shp'}
```

Even stranger, when i'm trying to add an unknown argument like :

```
Processing.runAlgorithm("qgis:voronoipolygons",layer,0.0, "test2.shp",0.0)
```

it returns :

```
File successfully loaded as tmp layer.
Error: Wrong parameter value: test2.shp
```

With adding 2 unknown arguments :

```
Processing.runAlgorithm("qgis:voronoipolygons",layer,0.0, "test2.shp",0.0,0.0)
```

TB :

```
File successfully loaded as tmp layer.
Error: Wrong number of parameters
ALGORITHM: Voronoi polygons
    INPUT <ParameterVector>
    BUFFER <ParameterNumber>
    OUTPUT <OutputVector>
```

Looks like there is a forth argument ... Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax is:

```
runAlgorithm(algOrName, onFinish, *args, **kwargs).
```

Just set None to onFinish argument.